# Event to alert when receive a token

Tags: solidity

I need to write a contract. That contract should detect and alert while receiving token/ether with some parameter. 
If somebody sends token/ether with some parameter to my contract. I need to know at the time of the transaction received.
Is any event available to do this function
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For this, you need to

1. Write a function that emits a so called `event`.
2. Events take parameters (the data you want to log). give the event a parameter of the type uint256 and put `msg.value` as that parameter when emitting the event.
3. write a listener, that listens to the triggering of such events.

Examples for all of this can be found here: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/contracts.html#events

Hint: If you put as `fromBlock: "latest"` in your listener script, it will not search for events in the past, but only give you triggered events in "real time".

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try and let you know

Comment: while I am using the event var event = clientReceipt.Deposit(); . Got ClientReceipt.Deposit is not a function . I am using web3 web3@1.0.0-beta.55

Comment: I have updated my question here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/73171/deposit-event-is-not-call-while-contract-get-token