# Deposit event is not call while contract get token

Tags: web3js, events, solidity-0.5.x

My contract
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

```
contract Transfereventaction {

    event Deposit(
        address indexed _from,
        bytes32 indexed _id,
        uint _value
    );

    function deposit(bytes32 _id) public payable {
        // Events are emitted using `emit`, followed by
        // the name of the event and the arguments
        // (if any) in parentheses. Any such invocation
        // (even deeply nested) can be detected from
        // the JavaScript API by filtering for `Deposit`.
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, _id, msg.value);
    }

}
```

Try with

```
const infura = "wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws";
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(infura));
```

also not working

My node js code

```
const infura = "ws://ropsten.infura.io/v3/id";
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(infura));
var ClientReceipt = new web3.eth.Contract(abi ,contract_address);

ClientReceipt.events.Deposit({
    fromBlock: "latest"
}, (error, event) => { console.log("Event result is "+ event); }).on('data', (event) => {
    console.log("data event"+event); // same results as the optional callback above
}).on('changed', (event) => {
    console.log("changed event" + event) // remove event from local database
})
.on('error', console.error);
```

emit is not call while token transfer to contract.

My node js code is in listen and it didn't print the console message while I send token to my contract

I need to know when the contract gets token. Pls guide me in the correct way

Pls let me know if I miss anything in the code

Answer (score 1):

You listen the event from the latest block so if your event is not in the latest one you don’t have any event. Try with `fromBlock: 6039496` for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but it is not working. Function not triggered while sending the token

Comment: Did you try `getPastEvents` and which version of `web3` do you use?

Comment: No i will try and let you know

Comment: I got "ClientReceipt.events.getPastEvents is not a function" error

Comment: I want to trigger a function while my contract receive a token

Comment: Which version on `web3` do you use?

Comment: My web3 version is web3@1.0.0-beta.55